# Create a template for a dialog box in C++/WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi

I would like to create a dialog box which gives the user the possibility to find a text that has been written in a box. If you look in your notepad.exe on Windows and head to the 'Search'-menu-entry, you will see the box I would like to create. Of course, FINDREPLACE and FindText(...) is able to show such a dialog box but this dialog box has the old windows style of Windows 95 (i guess).
Let's check it out, this is the notepad.exe FindText-DialogBox:

[image]

and this one has been created with C++ and the FINDREPLACE-stuff:

[image]

```
FINDREPLACE fr;
ZeroMemory(&fr, sizeof(fr));

fr.lStructSize = sizeof(fr);
fr.hwndOwner = hwndOwner;
fr.lpstrFindWhat = szFindWhat;
fr.wFindWhatLen = 80;
fr.Flags = FR_DOWN;

FindTextA(&fr);
```

Do you know how to create a dialog box which has the modern windows style? I think it has something to do with templates. But I don't know how to create a template and refer with fr.hInstance and fr.lpTemplateName to it.

Comment: Another name for dialog template is "Win32 DIALOG resource".  You should find many tools if you search for "Win32 DIALOG resource editor".  (Pedantically: ok, the template is the content of the DIALOG resource, and it's possible to build one directly in memory instead of loading a resource, but the design is very resource-centric)

Comment: Setting aside your proposed solution of making your own template, most likely all you need to do is "Enable Visual Styles".   See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cookbook-overview and https://stackoverflow.com/a/64038431/103167

Comment: Thank you very much. I had to enable 'Visual Styles'.

Answer (score 0):

You need manifest file. The app has to use so-called Common Controls `ComCtrl32.dll` and call `InitCommonControlsEx()` API. By this way your app says "I know about new Windows' styles and want to enable them." See this for example: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4987/Using-Windows-XP-Styles-in-your-MFC-WIN32-Applicat.